# SmartGWT DataSource adding QueryString to REST call

Tags: rest, tomcat, gwt, smartgwt

So, I have a Spring-MVC RESTful backend, that is cross-domain enabled.  It is unit-tested, I can call my web-services and get back the correct JSON.

I have a SmartGWT 5.1p and GWT 2.7.0 front-end application that works great in SuperDev mode or Classic Dev Mode, either works great. When I do this, I am using the old Firefox 24 browser with the GWT plugin, and I can see my app work just great.   My datasources are tied to RESTful web-services, and I can create, retrieve, update, and delete records via my DataSources.

I can compile the whole app via Maven, and get a WAR created just fine.  I tried moving this WAR over to a tomcat server, and it deploys correctly.  I can see the app running in tomcat with no errors in the logs.

Then when I go to the first page, the app comes up s normal with no errors.  The first thing I do is add a username and password into a form, and then it is supposed to call a LoginDataSource which is tied into a LoginCOntroller, or login web-service.

What I can see from firebug is that when I make my call, rather than just calling:

http://mydomain:8080/admin/login/user/myusername/pwd/mypassword

I get:

http://mydomain:8080/admin/login/user/myusername/pwd/mypassword?0{and a whole lotta stuff after this) ... the query string I presume.

When I hit the Submit button, I get a SERVER TRANSPORT error, and that's it, I don't get any more information that that.   There is nothing else to report from firebug except that the OPTIONS and GET add a whole lot of query string nonsense after the password.

I can look in the tomcat logs, and I don't see any errors in there at all.   I don't even see the URL call to the web-service.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.   I've been dealing with SmartGWT for years, and switched to back-end development for a while, and not I am trying to make my SmartGWT front-end work as well.   But, I am a little rusty as to what is happening now.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the source code of your `LoginDataSource`?

Comment: Can you add the code of the controller and the submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the querystring, it's the old base url I have in the datasource.   There is a method in each datasource called: getServiceRoot

In getServiceRoot, I was using a hardcoded "localhost:8080", which in client code that doesn't work. That means whoever is running the app in their browser, "localhost" means their machine.  So, I had to change the getServiceRoot to do the following:

```
protected String getServiceRoot()
{
    String baseUrl = "http://" + Window.Location.getHostName();
    return baseUrl + UrlConstants.SOME_URL_REST_ENDPOINT;
}
```

Since I have two WAR's on the same machine;
     one WAR is a Spring MVC back-end RESTful web-services
     the other WAR is the front-end, SmartGWT client application

This is a problem I run into ... I think just because both are on the same machine, that to the front-end, just call the code on the localhost, because it is there.  But to the browser, that could be any other machine.

I suppose I could have just hard-coded the public IP address of the machine running tomcat, and then the client-side SmartGWT would then certainly find the RESTful web-services.   Or, I could have used a Spring Env Profile to make that happen as well.  But the code change I made should work, provided both WARS are on the same machine.

I just got to remember that client-side code in a browser is relevant to the machine the browser is running on.

So, this is fixed.   If anyone needs any clarification, please let me know.

Comment: „***So, this is fixed***“ — How exactly did you fix it? My project's architecture is just like yours. 12.0p LGPL appends a „?isc_dataFormat=json“ to every URL. My backend API ignores it. I've tried setting `DSRequest.setParams(<empty Map>)` inside `RestDataSource.transformRequest()`. But it doesn't remove the query string. Nor does `OperationBinding.setDataProtocol(POSTMESSAGE)`..|  „***If anyone needs any clarification, please let me know***..“ | I need it! Please? I've read your SO posts from 2013-2017. You sound like you've mastered it :) Please push a working example to github? TIA!

Comment: @deduper here is a link to my REST Datasource, https://github.com/tjholmes66/RESTful-Phone-Book/tree/master/restful/src/main/java/com/opensource/restful/client/datasource, I don't remember any more details since this was so long ago.   The format I used for my ContactDataSource is a standard DataSource I used for the rest.  I think eventually I pulled out some common code and put that in more of a base class.  Hope this helps ...

Comment: By "_standard DataSource_" do you mean it extends RestDataSource? I see that you opted to toss SmartGWT's protocol and extract out only the data payload and pass it back. Clever! My implementation complies with SmartGWT's protocol. And I'm using Jersey vs Spring MVC. I understand why you took your approach. If I would've found your repo sooner, I might've done that too. But like the link in @CharlesKendrick's [_answer to another one of your questions_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15777421/4465539) explains: by not following SmartGWT's protocol, you've missed out on some compelling features!